# How to remove skinny triangles in scipy.spatial.Delaunay()

Tags: python, scipy, delaunay, qhull

I have a `scipy.spatial.Delaunay()` triangulation, and I would like to remove 'skinny' triangles from it. How would I do this?

I have seen that some other software (like here: [Houdini triangulate2d](https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/nodes/sop/triangulate2d.html)) have a 'minimum angle' option precisely to prevent skinny triangles. Is there some equivalent option for `scipy.spatial.Delaunay()`, or can someone provide a simple algorithm?

Comment: [Ruppert's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruppert%27s_algorithm) might be a good place to start. I think its the algorithm used in [MeshPy](https://pypi.org/project/MeshPy/)

Comment: @DrBwts Are `MeshPy` and `scipy.spatial.Delaunay()` interchangeable as far as Delaunay triangulations are concerned?

Comment: not as far as I'm aware. MeshPy is basically a wrapper for [Triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) (and also TetGen) which has much better control over the types of triangulation over domains with small angles.

Comment: @DrBwts Do you know of any other wrapper for `Triangle`? I could not figure out how to do a simple Delaunay triangulation of a point set using it. There's no obvious code for it.

Comment: why not just use Triangle?

Comment: I just discovered that there is a simple wrapper for `Triangle` in python, also called `triangle`.