# Delaunay triangulation using MeshPy

Tags: python, mesh, delaunay

I have been using `scipy.spatial.Delaunay()` till now to perform Delaunay triangulations of point sets. However, this often leads to the creation of skinny triangles, which I am trying to avoid. I was told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56136510/how-to-remove-skinny-triangles-in-scipy-spatial-delaunay) that `MeshPy` provides a wrapper to Shewchuk's `Triangle`, which allows for the construction of high-quality, adjustable meshes.

However, I have been not been able to find any sample code for creating a Delaunay triangulation using `Meshpy`, given only the nodes. The `MeshPy` site gives this basic example in 3d:

```
from meshpy.tet import MeshInfo, build

mesh_info = MeshInfo()
mesh_info.set_points([
    (0,0,0), (2,0,0), (2,2,0), (0,2,0),
    (0,0,12), (2,0,12), (2,2,12), (0,2,12),
    ])
mesh_info.set_facets([
    [0,1,2,3],
    [4,5,6,7],
    [0,4,5,1],
    [1,5,6,2],
    [2,6,7,3],
    [3,7,4,0],
    ])
mesh = build(mesh_info)
```

But supplying facets (or triangles) by hand is precisely what I don't want to do.

Note: The website for `Triangle` (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.delaunay.html) shows some quick code for Delaunay triangulation. But how would I do this in `MeshPy`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're unhappy with the quality of your triangular mesh, perhaps [optimesh](https://github.com/nschloe/optimesh) (a project of mine) is worth taking a look. Install with

```
pip install optimesh
```

and use it on the command line like

```
optimesh in.vtk out.e
```

You can also use it from within Python.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This looks nice. I was unable to tell from the website, what exactly are the inputs required for `optimesh` to generate its mesh? Do the points suffice? Or can we just give a geometric region (say, a disk) defined by a parametric equation?

Comment: @ap21 It's a mesh _optimizer_, so you'll need a mesh, i.e., points and cells.

Comment: Thank you. I see that `meshzoo` is another project of yours for generating meshes for simple surfaces. Very useful!